# gpg does not prompt for password - dwm

Tags: gpg, dwm, gpg-agent, password-store

I setup **gpg** with **pass** on a new computer and **pass** does not prompt me for the password of my **gpg** key, meaning I can't access my encrypted passwords on that computer.

What can I do?

when I run `pass somepassword` it just does not open a window to prompt me for a password.

I am using **dwm** with my own **.xinitrc**.

Comment: I have the password prompting working on my other computer though.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it turns out, I just had to install gtk2, because I was missing that package.